# apache rewriterule for tilda ~user folder

Tags: apache

I'm trying to get domain.com/~userX folders working without using userdir.

It works fine when the ~userX folders are in the server doc root doc folder, but there's too many and need to put them in a sub folder, ie /homepages so the best I've gotten is in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^~ "/homepages/%{REQUEST_URI}"

</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

With the trailing slash it works fine:
domain.com/~userX/

Without the trailing slash it automatically redirects to:
[http://ddomain.com/homepages/~userX/](http://ddomain.com/homepages/%7EuserX/)

Which I don't want, so I thought I would turn directory slash off:

```
 <Directory /var/www/domain/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                DirectorySlash Off
        </Directory>
```

The trailing slash still works but without the trailing slash I now get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

error log:

Cannot serve directory /var/www/domain/public_html/homepages/~userX

This is over my head, I've search for a few days and I'm really stuck :/

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1st Method:

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(~[^\/]+)(?:\/(.*)|$) /homepages/$1/$2 [L]
```

The trailing slash is present or not, it internally redirects with the trailing slash.

Issues:

1. I think, if the user enters an URL with a slash in a sub-directory of the /homepage directory, it is probably not going to work.

### 2nd Method:

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(~[^\/]+)$ /$1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^~ /homepages/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

### 3rd Method:

This might work better than the first and the second solution

```
RewriteRule ^(~[^\/]+)(?:\/(.*)|$) /homepages/$1/$2 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^\/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: #2 worked best for me as it redirect URL's without the trailing slash to the trailing slash! :) Thanks heaps! very much appreciated :) :)